# How to get update/deletes to a SAP HANA table?

Tags: hana, change-data-capture

I find ton of resources how to get into HANA but no material available how to retrieve data from a SAP HANA table? I am trying to get it to my java application. So trigger can only allow me to write to a different table.

Comment: Can you describe your use case in more detail? What do you mean by "get it into my java application"?

Comment: To retrieve data from a database table, you can use SELECT statements. Do you mean an other problem?

Comment: NO. like oracle change data capture. Let say I want to get changes done to a table in SAP HANA in continuous manner. HANA writes the changes to a queue where my java program can periodically go and get them. 
One solution I can think of is: create a trigger on a table which inserts new row for EVERY change with a time stamp. and I use my jdbc java code to query every few seconds to get recent changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check object changes in SAP HANA database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76264463/how-to-check-object-changes-in-sap-hana-database)