# How to check object changes in SAP HANA database?

Tags: abap, hana, change-tracking, sap-basis

I hope to obtain the list of all the changes in the SAP HANA database in a productive environment, with the user who made each of those changes

1. Through SQL query:

   ```sql
   SELECT
   OH.OBJECT_NAME,
   OH.OBJECT_TYPE,
   OH.SCHEMA_NAME,
   OH.USER_NAME,
   OH.OPERATION_TYPE,
   OH. TIMESTAMP
   FROM
   SYS.M_OBJECT_HISTORY OH
   WHERE
   OH.IS_PRODUCED = 'TRUE'
   ORDER BY
   OH.TIMESTAMP DESC;
   ```
2. Through transaction SE16 and table E070.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me which option is the most viable and if that option is described correctly.

I do not have access to a productive environment to test the above.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain the changes to the database without additional logging and auditing, like executed statements trace in HANA.

Note that **M_*** are monitoring views that provide actual HANA **runtime data**, including statistics and status information related to the execution of DML statements. Above mentioned view M_OBJECT_HISTORY is not available.

There is a reference of all available system views of HANA:
[SAP HANA SQL Reference Guide for SAP HANA Platform](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20cbb10c75191014b47ba845bfe499fe.html)

Table `E070` holds the headers of requests / tasks of the transport system, so it will not help to retrieve the database changes directly. The example content of the table:

[image: E070 content]

But of course it is possible to go deeper and analyze every transport request's task objects.